# Dot in a URl/SQL query not working

Tags: php, sql, apache

I have a URL path in my SQL query, which is retrieved from a URL variable, like so:

```
example.com/index.php?slug=path/to/url
```

This works fine and is able to query the database and get the required output.

However, when I introduce a dot, like so:

```
example.com/index.php?slug=path/to/url/page.htm
```

It doesn't work, even though it is in the database in exactly the same way.

Can you help me with this? Do I need to encode the dot somehow?

Thank you very much,

Sam

**Update**: As requested, the code:

```
$slug = $_GET['slug'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE slug='$slug'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Could you post the code you're using to create the SQL query please?

Comment: You don't need to encode the '.' can you share how you are building or preparing the SQL statement?

Comment: Are you using mysql_real_escape_string or PDO::quote?

Comment: Can you copy your query before execute it, and you can use `mysql_error();` to see what the problem in query like this `mysql_query("your query")or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: are you sure the second string exists in the database - what is the output of `SELECT * FROM pages WHERE slug='example.com/index.php?slug=path/to/url/page.htm'` executed directly against the DB?